# array formula in excel that returns the row number of the maximum value in a multiple-column range

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with format as follows:

[image: example of data format in pivot table]

I find the highest export quantity in all countries by the formula max(B2:D4) which comes out as 83.

Now I want to find the company name corresponding to this max value i.e. CompanyA in this case.

The actual pivot table has 241 rows and over 40 columns. But the layout is as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Approach would be following formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MAX(IF(B2:D4=MAX(B2:D4),ROW(B2:D4)-ROW(A1)+1)))
```

Entered as a matrix formula with SHift+Ctrl+Enter

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MAX(B2:D4),D2:D4,0))
```

Hope it's what you are looking for!

Comment: =INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MAX(B2:D4),B2:D4,0)) gives NA when I change value of C4 to 208

Comment: Sorry about that! I should have tested it more thoroughly. Yeah, the code above is great! My slight modification of it would be: =INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MAX(IF(B2:D4=MAX(B2:D4),ROW(B2:D4)-ROW(A1))))

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to use a `VLOOKUP` but this can only find columns to the right of the match, so to go to the left of a match try this solution, which uses the [***`MATCH()`***](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) and [***`INDEX()`***](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) functions:

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/left-lookup.html

Using your example image create 3 new columns (and then if you want combine them all into 1 by aggregating the formulas)

[image]

The formula for colum E is just your `MAX` function

For F it is this: `=MATCH(E2,B2:D2,0)`. The `MATCH()` function looks for the value contained in cell `E2` (which is the max of `B2:D2`) in the array `B2:D2` which is row `A` of your company values. The trailing `,0` in the function parameters tells the function to look for the *first exact* match. It thus returns the column where the max value occurred. You can then use the column to look up the names of the companies:

For G it is `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,1,F2)`